# Installing Node.js on Go Daddy VPS Windows Plesk

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, vps, plesk

can anyone help me install node.js on a Go Daddy VPS running Windows Plesk? I've never dealt with a VPS before and don't even know where to begin. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for installing/updating node.js. If you can connect your server through ssh you can follow the installation instructions on the previous link. Once you have nvm installed you can easily install your desired version of node.js running `nvm install x` where `x` is your desired version (for example, `4`, for the latest version). After installing node with the previous command, you just have to run `nvm use x` (again substituting `x` with your version) and you are ready to use node.js and npm.

If you don't have ssh access to the server, I would recommend enabling it to install node.js.

Comment: Hi Hawkings,
Thanks for the response! I noticed on the nvm github page it states that it does not support Windows. Is this still so? @hawkings

Comment: I think so, but they give you alternatives like [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) that work the same way, my instructions should still be valid for nvm-windows.